# how I install.packages("ggplot2")

Tags: ggplot2

hi I can't install ggplot2 package
my R studio version is 1.2.5033
and I try to install that with these packages but unfortunately don't install :

## install.packages("tidyverse")

## install.packages("ggplot2")

## install.packages("devtools")

devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive an error message? Are these tools already installed? Try `library(tidyverse)`. Another area to check is the "Packages" tab inside RStudio (in my version this is the bottom right pane, third tab) - see if those packages are there, and if so, they can be loaded with a check mark.